# Check for all entries in a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

say I have three tables:

DealerSellsCar: {[DealerID, CarID]}

Car: {[CarID, Color]}

Dealer: {[DealerID, Name]}

Primary keys are CarID, DealerID, CarID and DealerID as foreign keys.

Now: Say I have 6 different carIDs (1...6) and 3 Different DealerIDs ("1A", "2B", "3C") out of which only DealerID "3C" sells all cars (for 3C there is entry in DealerSellsCar for CarID (1...6)).

How would I query for the dealer(s) who sell all cars (IDs 1 to 6)?

I've tried:

```
select dsc.DealerID
from DealersellsCar dsc
where dsc.CarID = all (select CarID from Car)
```

Which didn't work. I get a column DealerID with no entries (when there should be the entry "3C"). I've also checked everything by hand to no avail.

Googling and searching here has yielded no results. I am sorry if this is a duplicate or if I've made myself unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select dsc.DealerID
from DealersellsCar dsc
group by dsc.DealerID 
having count(doc.DealerID) = (select count(c.id) from Car c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I am sort of disappointed in myself for not thinking of this way though because I know how aggregations work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it's better use join in that query to join all your keys:

```
select dsc.DealerID
from DealersellsCar dsc
inner join CarID c
on c.CarID = dsc.CarID
inner join Dealer d
on d.DealerID = dsc.DealerID
```

And this you can execute without errors and outputs DealerIDs with repetitions, if you need the DealerID without repetitions, you need to use distinct or group by:

```
select dsc.DealerID
from DealersellsCar dsc
inner join CarID c
on c.CarID = dsc.CarID
inner join Dealer d
on d.DealerID = dsc.DealerID
group by dsc.DealerID
```

Or:

```
select distinct dsc.DealerID
from DealersellsCar dsc
inner join CarID c
on c.CarID = dsc.CarID
inner join Dealer d
on d.DealerID = dsc.DealerID
```

What you prefer...